# Is it possible to make something like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a text box where someone can write some text to send me. I want to place some buttons on the page with some signs like "!", "XD" and "#".  When someone clicks, for example, the "!" button, the "!" should be inserted to the text box.  How can I do this?

```
<textarea data-typeid="18" data-price="15" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" name="ywapo_textarea_18[0]" cols="20" rows="4" maxlength="" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_textarea ywapo_price_fixed"></textarea>
<input onclick="InsertText('18','Ş')" value=" Ş " type="button">
<input onclick="InsertText('18','Ş')" value=" @ " type="button">
<input onclick="InsertText('18','Ş')" value=" # " type="button">
```

Comment: forgot your code?

Comment: Please always add your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you..

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  var input = $('.ywapo_input')
  input.val(input.val() + e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-typeid="18" data-price="15" data-pricetype="fixed" data-index="0" name="ywapo_textarea_18[0]" cols="20" rows="4" maxlength="" class="ywapo_input ywapo_input_textarea ywapo_price_fixed"></textarea>
<br/>
<button value="$">$</button>
<button value="@">@</button>
<button value="#">#</button>
```

Comment: i place my code.. i was try with <input onclick="InsertText('18','Ş')"...

Comment: @SmilMiau Updated my answer. Try this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but we can't really show you the code, it's not hard but it needs some time to be done...

Anyway, if you want to do stuff like this you should really take a look at AngularJS, that will be much more simple for you than using simple javascript (even if you can do something like this in simple JS, it's just way more difficult.)

Comment: @SmilMiau do not hesitate, i was using javascript only... if you can do something in 5 lines with JS, Angular will do it in only 1 line.

Comment: this is not an answer, please use comment section

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to update the `input`. Let there be three buttons with three different values, & on click of it, pass the value to input text

**JS**

```
function updateText(value) {
    document.getElementById("myInput").value = value;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="myInput">
<button type="button" value="!" onclick="updateText(this.value)">!</button>
<button type="button" value="XD" onclick="updateText(this.value)">XD</button>
<button type="button" value="#" onclick="updateText(this.value)">#</button>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/x2t34146/1/)